# Getting the result of an if else statement out of scope in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, scope

In this code I currently have the value of the addToOutput variable trapped inside an if else statement in a way that I am unable to get that value of the variable outside to the statement. I wish to get this value out so that when the user enters a number (for example 930) the function will output 900+30+0. To compile the results I have the variable "output" but if its unable to get the value from addToOutput I will not be able to get the desired result how can I make it so the value of addToOutput will be in scope?

```
function expandedForm(num) {

  let stringOfNumber = num.toString();
    let numberArray = Array.from(stringOfNumber);
    let zero = "0";
    let output;
    let addToOutput;
    for (let i=0; i<numberArray.length; i){
       let firstNumber = numberArray.shift();
       let arraySize = numberArray.length;

       ifElse(arraySize, firstNumber,zero)

       output = output + addToOutput;
    }
}

function ifElse (arraySize, firstNumber, zero, addToOutput){
    if(arraySize > 0){
      let numberOfZeros = zero.repeat(arraySize);
      addToOutput=firstNumber+ numberOfZeros + " + ";

      return(addToOutput);
    }
    else{
      addToOutput = firstNumber;
      return(addToOutput);
    }
 }
expandedForm(930);
```

Comment: You could use `var addToOutput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `addToOutput` parameter from `ifElse`, and just `return` the value you want returned (see `***` lines):

```
function ifElse (arraySize, firstNumber, zero){  // ***
    if(arraySize > 0){
      let numberOfZeros = zero.repeat(arraySize);
      return firstNumber+ numberOfZeros + " + "; // ***
    }
    else{
      return firstNumber;                        // ***
      return(addToOutput);
    }
}
```

Then when calling it, use that return value:

```
addToOutput = ifElse(arraySize, firstNumber, zero);
```

This is a programming fundamental (in JavaScript and many other languages): You pass data into a function, the function operates on the data, and returns the result. There's more to it than that, but that's the basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

Returning the value is a very good way of doing it, as stated in the first answer. However, I thought it would be worth adding some information about arguments by reference and by value.

What are often called "primitive" types (strings, numbers, booleans, etc) are passed by value, meaning changes in the value are lost when you leave the function. But objects are passed by reference, meaning changes remain after the function returns. So in your example above, all those are being passed by value. But imagine you did this instead:

```
 var o = {arraySize, firstNumber,zero, addToOutput};
 console.log(o.addToOutput);
 ifElse(o);
 console.log(o.addToOutput); // value may be different now!

 function ifElse (o) {
    if(o.arraySize > 0){
      let numberOfZeros = zero.repeat(o.arraySize);
      o.addToOutput=o.firstNumber+ numberOfZeros + " + ";
    }
    else{
      o.addToOutput = o.firstNumber;
    }
 }
```

Now you are passing an object `o` which contains your four parameters. And this is passed by reference, so changes will persist.

Again, this is just one more option to returning a value. If you need more than one return value it can be a helpful tool.